# MongoDB how to add field assinged by another filed

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDb `someCollection` containing field `field1`.
I want to add another field with values equal to `field1`. I do it like this:

```
db.someCollection.updateMany({}, {$set:{"newField": "$field1"}})
```

But the after update I got row like this

```
{"field1": "value1", "newField": "$field1"}
```

But expected result is:

```
{"field1": "value1", "newField": "value1"}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use update with pipeline. It looks almost the same, but the second part uses `[]`:

```
db.someCollection.updateMany({}, [{$set:{"newField": "$field1"}}])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pJ5jCZ68KSY)

Comment: For some reason I got `Wrong type for 'u'. Expected a object, got a array.` exception.

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: ` db.version()` returns 3.4.22

Comment: This is a very old version (2015), you need at least `$merge`, which I think was introduced on version 4.2, or you can use bulk update

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```js
db.someCollection.updateMany({}, [{$set:{"newField": {$expr: {$field: "field1"}}}]})
```

Comment: Do you think this answer is better in any way than the answer posted before it?

Comment: There's something wrong with curly brackets